# Woocommerce Gastos de Envío por unidades

Tags: woocommerce

Estoy montando una tienda en woocommerce de wordpress y me pregunto si es posible configurar los gastos de envío por unidad.

Por ejemplo, si vendo 1 unidad de cualquier producto serían 10 euros. Si vendo 2 unidades de cualquier producto, serían 8 euros y si vendo 3 unidades de cualquier producto 6 euros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final, buscando he encontrado este plugin Table Rate Shipping for WooCommerce, aquí dejo el link. https://codecanyon.net/item/table-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce/3796656

Es de pago pero va de fabula y es muy barato.